# How to get image buffer array from a video file Cocoa Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, avassetwriter, avasset

I want to get image buffers of a video file in disk to process it with asset writer for video compression. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle) to read the data from the device's storage and load it as `Data` in you code.

Works as `FileHandler` in other languages. Represents a pointer in the file, which can be moved and used to read or write.

The main methods to be aware of (for retrieving data) are:

- `readData(ofLength: Int) -> Data` which synchronously reads data up to the specified number of bytes.
- `seek(toFileOffset: UInt64)` which moves the file pointer to the specified offset within the file represented by the receiver.